# Return 1 to 7 days of a week from any given interval of dates

Tags: java, date, dictionary, jodatime

I want to return a map of days from an interval of dates :

1. From 1 to 7 days :

   ```
        From: "2016-02-09" to To: "2016-02-09" -> return : Tue
        From: "2016-02-09" to To: "2016-02-12" -> return : Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri
        From: "2016-02-02" to To: "2016-04-12" -> return : Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun, Mon (this should be sorted from Monday for the map)
   ```
2. Sorted map (week begins with Monday) with the `returned day as key`(String) and `value always = true` (boolean), will be reused for another purpose.

I want to use joda-time 2.8.1, but i'm not sure how to handle an interval of dates ?
I managed to get partially what i wanted but with only one day :

```
String input = "2016-02-09";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd" );
LocalDate localDate = formatter.parseLocalDate( input );
Locale locale = Locale.US;
DateTimeFormatter formatterOutput = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "E" ).withLocale( locale );
String output = formatterOutput.print( localDate ); //Result = Tue
```

Comment: You're right, thanks. I corrected my post. I should only return the map, the list was only to describe the results returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joda-Time does not support (closed) intervals of calendar dates, but only intervals of instants. So here an ad-hoc-workaround:

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse("2016-02-09");
LocalDate end = LocalDate.parse("2016-02-12");
if (start.isAfter(end))  {
    return Collections.emptyMap();
}

LocalDate current = start;
Map<Integer, Boolean> map = new TreeMap<>();

do {
    map.put(current.getDayOfWeek(), Boolean.TRUE);
    current = current.plusDays(1);
} while (!current.isAfter(end) && map.size() < 7);

LocalDate ref = new LocalDate(2016, 2, 7); // sunday
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E").withLocale(Locale.US);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int dayOfWeek : map.keySet()) {
    String output = f.print(ref.plusDays(dayOfWeek));
    sb.append(", ");
    sb.append(output);
}
System.out.println(sb.delete(0, 2).insert(0, "[").append(']').toString());
// [Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri]
return map;
```

Comment: The `while` loop could stop when the map size >= 7 so it doesn't loop unnecessarily.

Comment: Nice solution! May I ask what the purpose of `sb.delete(0,2)` at the end is in order to understand that better? Edit: Does it get rid of the comma?

Comment: @hamena314 `delete(0,2)` removes the leading comma which was inserted optimistically in for-each-loop. But of course, I don't pretend to win any code beauty price and can also imagine to introduce a boolean flag which is evaluated inside for-each-loop to decide if the comma must be printed or not. What is more disturbing is the fact that Joda-Time requires an extra formatter and date creation in order to print the names of day-of-week (another workaround for a missing feature).

Comment: Great solution Meno, thanks ! But i just updated my post as i didn't want to return the list also but only the map sorted from monday.

Comment: @user3557384 So you could use the stringbuilder part for debugging purposes only - maybe inside a block starting with `if (Global.DEBUG)`...

Answer (score 3):

First, shift your thinking to objects rather than strings. Strings may be your final output, but keep your business logic and data in objects.

## java.time

This Answer uses the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later.

These new classes were inspired by Joda-Time but are re-architected. Extended by the ThreeTenExtra project (whose `Interval` class may be useful here).

### `DayOfWeek`

The java.time framework includes a [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum. Make use of those objects. In other words do not think of strings as date-times; Strings are a textual representation of a date-time value.

The Map and List parts of your Question are confusing. Not sure what you want in your collections. But I'll show the basic ideas. You can use the `DayOfWeek` objects as keys or values in your maps and lists.

No need to specify a parsing pattern. Your strings are in ISO 8601 format. The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

```
List< DayOfWeek > dows = new ArrayList<>();

LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse( "2016-02-09" );
LocalDate stop = LocalDate( "2016-02-12" );
```

Loop by adding one day. Stop when we arrive at the stop date. This "half-open" approach is commonly used in date-time work where the beginning is inclusive while the ending is exclusive. For example, a week would be specified as starting on a Monday and running up to but not including the following Monday.

```
LocalDate d = start;
while ( d.isBefore( stop ) ) {
    DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.from ( d ); 
    dows.add( dow );
    d = d.plusDays( 1 );
}
```

### `Set`

Perhaps you are looking for a distinct list of day-of-week values occurring within a span of time. In that case, add to a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) rather than a `List`. The Set omits duplicates. If you want the results in a certain order use a [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html).

### Output Localized Strings

You can generate a String of each day’s name localized to a human language and abbreviated to cultural norms. Specify a Locale when asking the `DayOfWeek` enum to localize.

Note that in some languages (not English) a day of week has two different spellings depending on if it is used standalone or as part of a date. The `TextStyle` enum lets you specify either.

```
String output = dow.getDisplayName( TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );  // Or Locale.US etc.
```

Comment: I agree that using enums is nicer (here also with direct format support!). Not that I am not aware of this solution but I just limited my answer to Joda-Time because the OP has not signalled to be open to other possibly better solutions.

Comment: Nice solution indeed, but as Meno said, i can only use joda-time instead of java date and time classes.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to check only for the start and the end date. It is better because you will have 7 iterations at maximum:

```
    LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse("2016-02-09");
    LocalDate end = LocalDate.parse("2016-02-12");
    if (start.isAfter(end))  {
        return Collections.emptyMap();
    }
    Integer startDay = start.getDayOfWeek().getValue();
    Integer endDay = end.getDayOfWeek().getValue();
    if (startDay > endDay) {
        endDay += 7;
    }
    Map<DayOfWeek, Boolean> result = new LinkedHashMap<DayOfWeek, Boolean>();

    for (int i = startDay; i<=endDay; i++) {
        result.put(DayOfWeek.of(i), Boolean.TRUE);
    }
```